# what does the following code do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i created a project

```
demo
```

in rails. i then created a scaffolded application by giving

```
 rail_apps/demo> script server products title :stiring,description :text,url: string
```

Then i gave

```
 http://localhost:3000/products/
```

The products_controller.rb contains the following piece of code

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.xml
  def index
    @products = Product.find(:all)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @products }
end
  end
end
```

but i really cannot understand those four lines of code. can anyone give me a lead?

Answer (score 5):

```
@products = Product.find(:all)
```

fetches all products from database.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @products }
end
```

is a common pattern in RoR. Based on the request the controller renders a different view. For example if you request `/products` it will pass the products to the `index.html.erb` view which is just an html template. If the request is `/products.xml` it will serialize the products to a XML file and send this file as response.

Comment: thank u Darin, can u also tell me  respond_to is a loop or not? It seems to be a loop. In that case, the client will anyway request once. What is the real purpose of the do loop here?

Comment: @CHID, it is not a loop, it is a block. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.tokumine.com/2009/09/13/how-does-respond_to-work-in-the-rails-controllers/) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: You should mention that /products simply defaults to /products.html, with ".html" and ".xml" being known as the "format".

Answer (score 0):

To render the `index` action first find all products and assign them to the variable `@products`, then respond with either HTML or XML, depending on what the client wants (for example if the URL ends in `.xml` the client wants XML.

Render `index.html.erb` if the client wants HTML (Rails finds the template itself based on the controller name and action name, so `ProductsController` and `index` makes Rails look for `app/views/products/index.html.erb`.

Render XML from the `@products` variable if the client wants XML (Rails can automatically serialize an ActiveRecord object, or array of objects, as XML by looking at its properties).

Comment: response_to do |format| 
.
.
end
seems to be a loop kind of structure.. is it really a loop?

Comment: No, its more like a pattern matching clause. Think case/when (switch/case in Java/JS/C++).